# Download Multiple Uploaded Files

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I uploaded multiple files as bytes into database table and how to download files as zip now?  My code as below:
View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(Html.BeginForm("upload", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "form", enctype = "multipart/form-data" })))
        {
            <input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="files" id="files" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>
        }
```

controller:

```
    public FileContentResult GetFile(int id)
    {
        
        SqlDataReader rdr; byte[] fileContent = null;
        string mimeType = ""; string fileName = "";
        string constr = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbContextModel"].ConnectionString;

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            var qry = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE ID = @ID";
            var cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", id);
            con.Open();
            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (rdr.HasRows)
            {
                rdr.Read();
                fileContent = (byte[])rdr["Attachments"];

            }
        }
        return File(fileContent, "application/zip", "download.zip");
        
    }
```

Model:

```
  public partial class myTable
 {
  public int id {get;set;}
  public byte[] Attachments { get; set; }
  }
```

The download.zip file cannot be opened. "The compressed zipped folder is invalid". Please advise. Thanks in advance.

upload function:

```
...
     byte[] bytes = new byte[] { 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20 };
            MemoryStream target = new MemoryStream();
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                if (file.ContentLength > 0)
                { 
                     file.InputStream.CopyTo(target);
                    bytes = target.ToArray();
               
                }
                
            }
```

Comment: That will depend entirely on how you have saved the uploaded files in your database. You haven't shown that code, but based on the code you *have* shown, you need to have added the uploaded files into a zip file before saving them. If you've just appended the data from each file into one stream, that won't be a valid zip file, and you won't have any way to extract the original files from it either.

Comment: You are right, I appended the data into one stream because there is only one attachments field in the table (I added the code above). What is the best way and how to implement multiple files upload and download? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Appending the data for each uploaded file into a single stream doesn't create a valid zip file. You need to generate a valid zip file to store in the database.

For example:

```
byte[] bytes;
var target = new MemoryStream();
using (var zip = new ZipArchive(target, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
{
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        string name = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        ZipArchiveEntry entry = zip.CreateEntry(name);
        using (Stream entryStream = entry.Open())
        {
            file.InputStream.CopyTo(entryStream);
        }
    }
    
    bytes = target.ToArray();
}
```

[ZipArchive Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchive)

Comment: Thanks. I modified my upload function as above, the compressed zip file download.zip is still invalid. I guess my GetFile function to unzip the bytes from the database is not correct format?

Comment: The code works fine for me, and generates a valid zip file. Are you sure the record you're downloading from was created by the new code?

Comment: I have the exactly same code as yours. My function accepts files as: IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files

Comment: Well either the bytes aren't being saved properly in the database, or the record you're trying to load was created before you fixed the code to create a zip file.

Comment: how to do read the bytes to zip file?